# Changing video based on the dropdown In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to change  the video src with Jquery on change of a dropdown list.

Here is my Jquery Scripting Code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#videoSelect").change(function() {
                var videoValue = $(this).val();

                if(videoValue==1){
                    console.log("Inside"+videoValue);
                    $("#video2").attr('src','video/1.mp4');
                }
                else if(videoValue==2){
                    console.log("Inside"+videoValue);
                    $("#video2").attr('src','video/2.mp4');
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Inside"+videoValue);
                    $("#video2").attr('src','video/3.mp4');
                }

            }); 
            });
</script>
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="videoSelect">
          <option value="1">Higher Education in India </option>
          <option value="2">Sardar Vallabh Bhai Patel</option>
          <option value="3">Maulana Abul Kalam Azad</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <video width="100%" height="202px" controls=""> 
            <source id="video2" src="video/Education In India.mp4" type="video/mp4">                       
            <object width="260" height="150" type="application/x-mplayer2">
                <param name="fileName" value="video/movie.swf">
                <param name="autostart" value="0">
            </object>
        </video>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What is see is the code is working properly and the on selection of dropdown the **video "src"** attribute value changes(as I analyse using Inspect Element), but the video itself doesn't change,instead playing the Initial video.

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Hello already tried with .prop() but with no luck.

Comment: Check your paths. Original src is "video/Education In India.mp4" but in jquery your path for videos 1 is "video/1.mp4"

Comment: Correction: <source id="video2" src="video/1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> instead of  <source id="video2" src="video/Education In India.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as complete Suvojit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the id="video2" on to the video tag instead of the source tag, Then it works.